# Where is the capacitive coupling in this adafruit soil moisture sensor?

Tags: capacitive, coupling

Here is the moisture sensor:
https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-stemma-soil-sensor-i2c-capacitive-moisture-sensor/downloads

It has a large copper area insulated with soldermask that sticks in the soil.

My understanding is that moisture in the soil changes the electrical permitivity of the soil, and thus affects the capacitance. However there's only one copper polygon fill on the pcb to serve as one side of a capacitor, and I'd like to understand what it is capacitively coupled to.

[image: PCB with plate in red]

If the rest of the circuit is floating, presumably it needs to couple back to the circuit otherwise the microcontroller wouldn't be able to drive the capacitance. I can't see any provision for this though.

Comment: Is there any evidence that the product is effective at what it claims to be able to do? Is that evidence believable?

Comment: Aside from Andy's very valid point: where's the capacitive coupling in e.g. a smart phone? Typically, it's a "virtual" capacitor, where the other side is "ground" (not in the soil sense, more in the "large mass of immovable charge")

Comment: @Andyaka I can't be sure. The adafruit forums suggest mixed results but there'll be some selection bias in that sample.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I saw something about this online but don't understand. Is the point that your body is sufficiently large that you can alter its distribution of charge?